# Python Environment variable within environment variable

Tags: python, shell, unix, environment-variables

I'm trying to set up an environment variable via **Python**:

```
os.environ["myRoot"]="/home/myName"
os.environ["subDir"]="$myRoot/subDir"
```

I expect the `subDir` environment variable to hold `/home/myname/subDir`, however it holds the string `'$myRoot/subDir'`. How do I get this functionality?

(Bigger picture : I'm reading a json file of environment variables and the ones lower down reference the ones higher up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [os.path.expandvars](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars) to expand environment variables like so:

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.path.expandvars("My home directory is $HOME")
My home director is /home/Majaha
>>>
```

For your example, you might do:

```
os.environ["myRoot"] = "/home/myName"
os.environ["subDir"] = os.path.expandvars("$myRoot/subDir")
```

I think @johntellsall's answer is the better for the specific example you gave, however I don't doubt you'll find this useful for your json work.

Edit: I would now recommend using @johntellsall's answer, as os.path.expandvars() is designed explicitly for use with paths, so using it for arbitrary strings may work but is kinda hacky.

Answer (score 2):

Use `os.environ` to fetch the value, and `os.path` to correctly put slashes in the right places:

```
os.environ["myRoot"]="/home/myName" 
os.environ["subDir"] = os.path.join(os.environ['myRoot'], "subDir")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fix_text(txt,data):
    '''txt is the string to fix, data is the dictionary with the variable names/values'''
    def fixer(m): #takes a regex match 
         match = m.groups()[0] #since theres only one thats all we worry about
         #return a replacement or the variable name if its not in the dictionary
         return data.get(match,"$%s"%match) 
    return re.sub("$([a-zA-Z]+)",fixer,txt) #regular expression to match a "$" followed by 1 or more letters

with open("some.json") as f: #open the json file to read
    file_text= f.read()
data = json.loads(file_text) #load it into a json object
#try to ensure you evaluate them in the order you found them
keys = sorted(data.keys() ,key=file_text.index) 
#create a new dictionary by mapping our ordered keys above to "fixed" strings that support simple variables
data2= dict(map(lambda k:(k,fixer(data[k],data)),keys)
#sanity check
print data2
```

[edited to fix a typo that would cause it not to work]

Comment: I think a good explanation is required, I am guessing the OP is not overly experienced and using `with` to open the file or at least closing it would be better too ;)

Comment: meh I suppose you are right .... good practice and all ... still the file is opened and read from and then garbage collected ... `with` and `close` for reading files is not very important(but probably still a good practice for a new coder) ...

Comment: yep, not so essential in this question but definitely using `with` can help avoid some headaches later.